# I believe my code is formatted correctly but still getting `syntax error near unexpected token 'fi'`

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to make a menu for a BASH app, and getting an error with 'fi'

This is the code:

```
chmod u+x main.sh

menu() {
  clear
  echo 1. Option A
  echo 2. Option B
  read input
if [ $input == "1" ] ;
  then
  a()
  fi
if [ $input == "2" ] ;
  then
  b()
  fi
}

a(){
#code
}

b(){
#code
}

menu
```

I have made sure I put spaces around brackets, then on a new line, and added semicolons I really don't know why this it's doing this, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you don't need to put a semicolon at the end of a condition in an `if` statement if you don't put `then` on the same line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In bash, the function call syntax doesn't use the parentheses:

```
a  # not a()!
```

Comment: oh yeah I called `menu` correctly, but forgot to call `a` and `b` correctly, thank you for your help it works.